# Office 365 unified API (preview) - Remove User from Group

Tags: office365

The documentation for Office 365 unified API (beta) does not mention how to remove a user from a group once you add them.  There is code to unsubscribe (not the same as removing), but it's only for the currently logged-in user.

I tried getting the user ID and issuing a DELETE (using /groups/xxxxxxxxx/members/yyyyyyyyyy), but it does not allow this.  I can't even find the record ID that would correspond to a member (rather than a user).

How do I remove a user from a group using the API?

Comment: I know that we can delete the group, recreate and then re-add the appropriate users, but then everybody gets another welcome email.  Not a good workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete a member of a group: 
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/myorganization/groups(‘gid’)/members(‘uid’)/$ref

Comment: Had a typo above...DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/myorganization/groups(‘gid’)/member/(‘uid’)/$ref